# Hashtag in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loopbackjs

I'm using AngularJs as my frontend and Loopback as my backend API. I'm trying to add hashtag(#) functionality to the webapp I'm working on..  My string is `$scope.postText`.I need to separate all the words starting with '#'.
Please suggest me some the best to achieve this. Also it would be nice to hilight the words with hashtag while typing itself(like facebook).Please let me know if you know how to do this too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please edit your question?

Comment: use Javascript str.split() function and check which ones start with #?

Comment: @Tom can you please explain how to do that..?I want all the words that start with # in a seperate array.I know I should use split(),but I'm getting confused while trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var re = /(?:^|\W)#(\w+)(?!\w)/g, match1, matches1 = [];
while (match1 = re.exec($scope.postText))
{
  matches1.push(match1[1]);
              }
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use can create filter for this -

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .filter('split', function() {
        return function(input, char, index) {

            return input.split(char)[index];
        }
    });

{{input | split:'#':0}}
```

Have fun..!!

Comment: not working.. I want all the words that start with hashtag in  a seperate array..

Answer (score 0):

For highlighting hashtags as you type just like facebook:
https://github.com/sujeet100/ngHashtags

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Tom in the comments section, you could write a function that uses the "split" method like so:

```
function octothorpSplitter(hashtagString) {

  var res = hashtagString.split('#');

  res.shift(); //gets rid of unnecessary first element

  return res;

}

octothorpSplitter("#OneString#2ndStringWithNumbers#3rdWith$pecialCharacters!");

//result: [ 'OneString',  '2ndStringWithNumbers',  '3rdWith$pecialCharacters!' ]
```

Just pass in your own variable -  `$scope.postText`  - instead.